# Mysql Union Left Join Group Concat

Tags: mysql, union, group-concat

I need help with this Mysql query

```
Select id, code, Tbldetail from TblProd
```

The result is:

```
id       code            detail        (i Need ADD Model Column Here)
100    432320-1         Keyboard
101    432325-1         Mouse
102    432329-1         Printer
```

I have another table with this structure:

```
id     code             model 
1     432320-1           rx1
2     432320-1           rx2
3     432320-1           rx3
4     432325-1           rx1
5     432329-1           rx2
6     432329-1           rx1
```

I need an output like this:

```
id       code            detail               Model
100    432320-1         Keyboard          rx1,rx2,rx3
101    432325-1         Mouse             rx1
102    432329-1         Printer           rx2,rx1
```

How can I perform this?

Comment: Very hard to read.  Can you format it a bit better, please?

Answer (score 2):

It's exactly what you say in the title:

```
SELECT p.id, p.code, p.detail, GROUP_CONCAT(m.model ORDER BY m.model) as model
FROM TblProd AS p
LEFT JOIN TblModel AS m ON p.code = m.code
GROUP BY p.id
```

Comment: Adding the DISTINCT keyword in the GROUP_CONCAT would return the same result, at least for the specified example. Adding an ORDER BY to the GROUP_CONCAT would make the return value more deterministic. (Without that, MySQL could return `'rx2,rx3,rx1'` for the GROUP_CONCAT.  The specification doesn't mention any requirement about not returning duplicates, and the order of the model values may not be important. +10.

Comment: @spencer7593 While there may be applications where `DISTINCT` is needed, this doesn't look like it. But getting consistent ordering is reasonable, so I've added that to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

There's a couple of ways to get that result.

One alternative to a LEFT JOIN is to use a correlated query in the SELECT list.

```
 SELECT t.id
      , t.code
      , t.detail
      , ( SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT r.model ORDER BY r.model)
            FROM TblModel r
           WHERE r.code = t.code
        ) AS model  
  FROM TblProd t
 ORDER BY t.id
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT a.id, a.code, a.detail, GROUP_CONCAT(b.model) as model
FROM TblProd AS a,TblModel AS b ON a.code = b.code
GROUP BY a.id
```

Comment: Isn't time already to ditch the old-school comma operator the inner join operation, and use the JOIN keyword instead? Also, OP mentions making use of an outer join in the question title.

Comment: Really Thanks for your Help

Comment: You can improve your answer by including an explanation of why this solves the problem.